# Having trouble setting the state of student submission when sending a grade

Tags: google-classroom

I am having trouble trying to send a grade from an external tool to Google Classroom.  I can send the grade (assignedGrade and draftGrade) and I can change them.  I see my changes in the returned student submission, and in the student submission history but I can never convince Classroom that the assignment has been "Graded" or "Done". Looking at the student's work as the teacher I see the following:

[image: Grade history, but ungraded]

All my attempts to store the grade are there, but they are still "ungraded".  Here is the code I am using to set the grades:

```
$sub = new Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission();
$sub->setAssignedGrade(48);
$sub->setDraftGrade(48);
$sub->setState('TURNED_IN');  // Worked with no apparent effect
$opt = array('updateMask' => 'assignedGrade,draftGrade');
$retval = $studentSubmissions->patch($gc_course, $gc_coursework, $submit_id, $sub, $opt);
```

This is mostly working - the new grades appear, and an new entry appears in my instructor history but it is never *graded*. :(

When I dump out retval, above I see the grades, and the state never changes (some fields below):

```
object(Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission)#90 (27) {
  ["assignedGrade"]=>
  int(48)
  ["assignmentSubmissionType":protected]=>
  string(45) "Google_Service_Classroom_AssignmentSubmission"
  ["assignmentSubmissionDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["associatedWithDeveloper"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["courseId"]=>
  string(10) "9...9"
  ["courseWorkId"]=>
  string(10) "8...2"
  ["courseWorkType"]=>
  string(10) "ASSIGNMENT"
  ["creationTime"]=>
  string(24) "2017-11-29T20:07:51.332Z"
  ["draftGrade"]=>
  int(48)
  ["id"]=>
  string(19) "CgwIy.....uh4"
  ["late"]=>
  NULL
  ["state"]=>
  string(7) "CREATED"
```

I so am hopeful that I am missing one little thing.   I played a little with the concept of turn in:

```
$turnin = new Google_Service_Classroom_TurnInStudentSubmissionRequest();
$retval = $studentSubmissions->turnIn($gc_course, $gc_coursework, $submit_id, $turnin);
```

But that seemed not to help much.  Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I found my particlar problem, helped greatly by comparing my problem with this related question [Classroom API Submitted Grades and Return State Not Showing In Classroom UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563245/classroom-api-submitted-grades-and-return-state-not-showing-in-classroom-ui)

My error was because I was not setting maxPoints when creating the CourseWork item (way before I was patching the grades):

```
$cw = new Google_Service_Classroom_CourseWork();
$cw->setTitle($lti->title);
$cw->setMaterials($materials);
$cw->setMaxpoints(100);   // This was missing
$cw->setWorkType("ASSIGNMENT");
$cw->setState("PUBLISHED");
```

Once I set maxPoints - the grades were flowing and started appearing nicely in the Instructor UI.